# Use Meteor 1.4 modules together with Require.js (require keyword conflict)

Tags: javascript, meteor, sense

I have the issue that I need to use a modified version require.js which already uses the keyword require.

Now with Meteor 1.4 modules require is also a keyword, so I have a conflict... How can I use them together?

I got a tip from someone that I should ask:

> "how you would go about getting requirejs page on the page and
>   exporting a amd module if you wanna use it from within a commonjs
>   module"

Example Qlik Sense code that works without the modules package in Meteor:

```
function setupQlikSenseDivs() {
require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
       var app = qlik.openApp(Meteor.settings.public.multipleDivAppGuid, qConfig);        
        var options = {};
        //get Chart objects -- inserted here --           
        app.getObject('QV01', 'Ggpaxa', options); //sales by country bar
       linechart
    })
```

}